# How to append dictionary values via recursion with user input in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, append, billing

I have created a method called 'ads' inside of a larger Class. The method should take user input and append the value slot (0) of the dictionary with this data. The dictionary keys, however, are already defined and should not change.

This section of the program is meant to append the placeholder value of 0 to a user input float value representing hours *using recursion*. These 'hours' (or float) values should be values that are associated with keys that represent days of the week (EX: M, T, W, TH, F, S, SUN)

An example of how I would like the dictionary to look after the program runs:

```
        ads_dict = {'M': 4.2, 'T': 6,'W': 3.5,'TH': 2.2, 'F': 4.3, 'S': 2, 'SUN': 4.1}
```

The current code is missing elements but this is how it stands as of now... (Please note I am fairly new to my CS studies and would appreciate it if you could explain like I am 5 years old):

```
@property
        def ads(self):
            for k,v in ads_dict.items():
                v = input('Enter Hours In Adult Day Service')
                ads_dict.append(v)

            ads_dict = {'M': 0, 'T': 0,'W': 0,'TH': 0, 'F': 0, 'S': 0, 'SUN': 0}

            
            return self._ads
```

I felt it appropriate to create a new post for this question as I could not find previous questions asked about appending dictionaries specifically with recursion using input from end-user. Thank you!

Comment: you should create `ads_dict = {...}` before you run `for`-loop.

Comment: dictionary doesn't have `.append()` but `ads_dict[k] = v`

Comment: I don't see any recursion in your code. `for`-loop is NOT recursion.

Comment: `input()` always gives string (even if use write number) and you have to use `float(v)`

Answer (score 0):

I see few mistakes in code

- you should create `ads_dict` before `for`-loop
- dictionary doesn't use `.append()` but `ads_dict[k] = v
- `input()` always gives string (even if use write number) so you need convert it `float(v)
- code could be more useful if you would display day name in `input()`
- I have no idea what is `self._ads`

```
@property
def ads(self):
    
    ads_dict = {'M': 0, 'T': 0,'W': 0,'TH': 0, 'F': 0, 'S': 0, 'SUN': 0}

    for key, value in ads_dict.items():
        value = input(f'Enter Hours In Adult Day Service for {key}: ')
        ads_dict[key] = float(value)

    return ads_dict
```

Of couser you could use also `.keys()` instead of `.items()` because you don't use original values from dictionary.

```
@property
def ads(self):
    
    ads_dict = {'M': 0, 'T': 0,'W': 0,'TH': 0, 'F': 0, 'S': 0, 'SUN': 0}

    for key in ads_dict.keys():
        value = input(f'Enter Hours In Adult Day Service for {key}: ')
        ads_dict[key] = float(value)

    return ads_dict
```

Or you could create empty dictionary and use list with keys

```
@property
def ads(self):
    
    ads_dict = {}
    
    for key in ['M', 'T', 'W', 'TH', 'F', 'S', 'SUN']:
        value = input(f'Enter Hours In Adult Day Service for {key}:' )
        ads_dict[key] = float(value)

    return ads_dict
```